# Match Regex on URL ending with 32 characters

Tags: regex, url

Trying to write a regex to match URLs in the following format

https://www.test.com/module/1dfce6a564rn184930d829205943373e
https://www.test.com/directory/67a58dc9165ti206461d34fe1783a7e1

There will always be one subdirectory after the domain. They will always end in a 32 alphanumeric character string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what have you tried? 2nd line have 33 alphanumeric character

Comment: try this: ```.+\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{32})``` on https://regex101.com/

Comment: _There will always be one subdirectory after the domain_ then try: ```https:\/\/.+\/.+\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{32})```

Comment: I'm not great with regex but tried this so far ((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([0-9a-z]{32}) and it's not working correctly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Let me summarize your problem:

- url must be http/https/ftp
- url must have 1 directory before file name
- file name in url must be 32 alphanumeric character

Your attempt: `((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([0-9a-z]{32})`

Test string:

- [MUST MATCH] https://www.test.com/module/1dfce6a564rn184930d829205943373e
- [MUST MATCH] https://www.test.com/directory/67a58dc9165ti206461d34fe1783a7e1
- [MUST NOT MATCH] https://www.tesaaat.com/sss/6ssssssssssssssss7a58dc9165ti206461d34fe1783a7e1
- [MUST NOT MATCH] https://www.test.com/directory1/directory2/67a58dc9165ti206461d34fe1783a7e1
- [MUST NOT MATCH] 123123123123https://www.test.com/directory1/directory2/67a58dc9165ti206461d34fe1783a7e1
- [MUST NOT MATCH] test.com/directory1/directory2/67a58dc9165ti206461d34fe1783a7e1

Your approach is already correct. You just need to make sure that after those 32 characters, there's no more character. So you need to add `$` in the end.

Also, the schema (http/https/ftp) is in capture group. That means if there's a schema (http/https/ftp), it will be captured, but it doesn't have to exist. So, just add a 1 quantifier to the schema capture group `{1}`.

Answer: `((http[s]?|ftp):\/){1}?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([0-9a-z]{32})$`

[image]

[image]

Another possible improvement is adding `^` at the start. This will make sure that line that does not begin with http/https/ftp will not match.

Regex: `^((http[s]?|ftp):\/){1}?\/?([^:\/\s]+)((\/\w+)*\/)([0-9a-z]{32})$`

Will not match: `test.com/directory1/directory2/67a58dc9165ti206461d34fe1783a7e1`

For trying your regex, you can use online tool regex101.com. It explains what your regex means in right panel. For example, mine was explained as such

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you cracked it. However I'm still getting few issues. It still matches on https://www.test.com/directory1/directory2/67a58dc9165ti206461d34fe1783a7e1 and also how do I match it on the full match only?

Comment: what issue exactly?

Comment: It still matches on test.com/directory1/directory2/67a58dc9165ti206461d34fe1783a7e1 and also how do I match it on the full match only?

Comment: `{1}` quantifier is completely useless. Only word character `\w` is really poor for a directory name.